# How to extract single column as vector from data frame

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, extract, numeric

I have a file that has been saved as a binary compressed file that I recall using the following command

```
rates.data = readRDS(paste("~/Documents/.../..../RatesData/", 
"2013-01-14", ".rds", sep = ""))
```

Which gives me:

```
rates.data
#            Date USSW1 USSW2 USSW3 USSW4 USSW5 USSW7 USSW10 USSW30
# 3271 2013-01-14  0.31  0.38  0.50  0.67  0.89  1.34   1.88   2.83
```

But, I want only the rate.  I have tried the following:

```
rates.data[2:9]
# USSW1 USSW2 USSW3 USSW4 USSW5 USSW7 USSW10 USSW30
# 3271  0.31  0.38  0.50  0.67  0.89  1.34   1.88   2.83

rate.data[1,[2:9]] this does not work
```

This gives me only one element...

```
rates.data[1,2]
[1] "0.31"
```

...or as a numeric:

```
as.numeric(rates.data[1,2])
[1] 0.31
```

But, I still can't get the vector.  How do I extract the vector?

```
str(rates.data) # returns the following - so its actually a data frame

'data.frame':   1 obs. of  9 variables:
$ Date  : chr "2013-01-14"
$ USSW1 : chr "0.31"
$ USSW2 : chr "0.38"
$ USSW3 : chr "0.50"
$ USSW4 : chr "0.67"
$ USSW5 : chr "0.89"
$ USSW7 : chr "1.34"
$ USSW10: chr "1.88"
$ USSW30: chr "2.83"
```

Comment: Try `as.numeric(rates.data[1,2:9])` or, even better `as.numeric(rates.data[1,-1])`

Comment: When slicing dataframes, row-indices come before the comma, column-indices come after. If you omit the comma, like `rates.data[2:9]`, your column-indices will get misinterpreted as row-indices, not what you want. As for `rates.data[1,[2:9]]`, the second set of parens is wrong syntax and unnecessary anyway. `df[row-indices , col-indices]` is all you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @nograpes suggested.

```
as.numeric(rates.data[, 2:9])
## [1] 0.31 0.38 0.50 0.67 0.89 1.34 1.88 2.83
```

Comment: Thanks, intuitively obvious once the answer is provided

Answer (score 0):

`rates.data[,2:9]`

`df[row-indices , col-indices]` is all you need, and you can omit one if you specify the other, so here we just give col-indices.

(If you omit the comma, like `rates.data[2:9]`, this still gets treated as column-indices, but it's sloppy.)